# Are there Recent Studies of Price Elasticity of Demand for Housing in England?

Tags: reference-request, housing

To address what is widely perceived as under-supply of housing in England resulting in high costs of housing, the UK government has set a target of 300,000 new homes annually (the target relates to England only because housing policy in Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland is the responsibility of their devolved administrations).  I am interested in assessing the effect that achieving that target over a period of years would have on the cost of housing (for both buyers and renters).

Are there any recent (say last 10 years) academic studies of the own-price elasticity of demand for housing in England (or for the whole of the UK)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working paper  by [Auterson (2014)](https://obr.uk/docs/dlm_uploads/WP06-final-v2.pdf) which estimates that the price elasticity of demand for housing in UK was $-0.92$, but it is an auxiliary result as the paper's main intent was to forecast the housing prices in UK not to estimate elasticity - might be still useful though.